Not able to run libcurl sample example after compiling it from GIT source with cmake
I downloaded my source code from GIT link (https://github.com/curl/curl) and build it with cmake GUI

It did show issues with ZLIB, LibPSL, LibSSH2 which I was not able to resolve.
and I did get the below files, after compiling with VS2019

Now I am trying to run below sample code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res gets the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}

With below error:
1>------ Build started: Project: CURL_CPP, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>CURL_CPP.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libcurl.lib(multi.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt referenced in function multi_wait
1>libcurl.lib(cf-socket.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt
1>libcurl.lib(cf-socket.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_send
1>libcurl.lib(multi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_send
1>libcurl.lib(asyn-thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_send

I am not able to resolve the error, despite trying everything I could find online. Can someone please help?
My project setting are as below:

The lib path is also correct as below


Please don't post text in pictures, post text/errors as code.

Does this answer your question? Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl

Link with libcurl_imp.lib or define the macro as in the dupe.

@273K I had tried the solution in the link and it did not work Unresolved symbols when linking a program using libcurl

@273K Removed text/errors as pictures and posted as text/errors. Can you please take back the negative vote?

I had tried the solution in the link and it did not work This is not true, the solution worked, you moved forward and got other errors. You seemed to be banned by Google, otherwise you would find a solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/864367/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-select-referenced-i

As suggested in the comment by @273K, linking with libcurl_imp.lib seems to be working.
